# SSDT Database projects Code Analysis integration with SonarQube

Tags: c#, sonarqube, code-analysis, sql-server-data-tools, sonar-runner

I am currently in the process of writing code analysis rules for SSDT database projects for our company. We currently have SonarQube implemented for our C# projects, and our development director wanted me to integrate the SSDT Db project code analysis into SonarQube.

I am pretty new to SonarQube and have been doing a lot of googling, and I have found out how to run the SonarQube scanner using MSBuild which seems to be the right direction to head in. However, I have been unable to figure out how to get the scanner to pick up the results of my analysis.

You can test this out with the built in MSFT rules by adding this argument to your msbuild command line: /p:RunSqlCodeAnalysis=true. You can also optionally control which rules to run using /p:SqlCodeAnalysisRules=.

The question: How do I get SonarQube to generate a report from the code analysis results?

Comment: In addition here is this info:

SonarQube Server: 5.2
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner: 1.0.2
MSBuild: 4.6.1085.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to push the analysis results to SonarQube you need to execute the following command after the project is built:

```
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
```

Please, check the following article for more information:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+the+Command+Line

If you are using TFS you might be interested in our TFS extension, which can be found here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube

Comment: Thanks Valeri, we are looking at the MSBuild Scanner now. It looks promising. We thought we might have to build a custom plugin but this may work for us.

Comment: @Valeri SSDT runs on .sql files. Since we've plug-ins only for C#, JavaScript & Java, no file is being picked up even when we run `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end`. Do we need a separate plug-in that works .sql files?

Comment: Yes, you would need an additional plugin to analyze SQL files. We currently provide only [PL/SQL plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPLSQL), but we hope to add support for T-SQL later this year.